# Can I force nHibernate to persist a new entity with the same ID as an already-loaded entity?

Tags: nhibernate, object-model

My project has a `Ticket` entity with an `OwnedBy` property. I'm using nHibernate to persist the tickets to a database.

The canonical source for potential ticket owners is Active Directory. Since I don't want to have to query Active Directory every time I load tickets, I *also* persist `Ticket.OwnedBy` to the database and load it from *there* when fetching tickets.

When a ticket's owner is reassigned, I get the new `Owner` from Active Directory and assign it to `Ticket.OwnedBy`, then call Session.SaveOrUpdate(ticket). When I commit the transaction, NHibernate throws a `NonUniqueObjectException` because an `Owner` with the same ID is already associated with the session.

#### Class definitions

```
class Ticket {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Owner OwnedBy { get; set; }
    /* other properties, etc */
}
class Owner {
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    /* other properties, etc */
}
```

#### Fluent nHibernate Mappings

```
class TicketMap : ClassMap<Ticket> {
    public TicketMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.OwnedBy)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Not.Nullable();
        /* other properties, etc */
    }    
}
class OwnerMap : ClassMap<Owner> {
    public OwnerMap() {
        Id(x => x.Guid)
            .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        /* other properties, etc */
    }
}
```

#### Sample code

```
// unitOfWork.Session is an instance of NHibernate.ISession
Ticket ticket = unitOfWork.Session.Get<Ticket>(1);
Owner newOwner = activeDirectoryRepo.FindByGuid(/* guid of new owner, from user */);
ticket.OwnedBy = newOwner;
unitOfWork.Session.SaveOrUpdate(ticket);
unitOfWork.Commit(); // Throws NonUniqueObjectException
```

I want nHibernate to overwrite the properties of the existing `Owner` with the properties of the unattached one. (The Name or Email in the object I fetched from AD may be different, and AD is supposed to be the canonical source.) I've tried calling `Session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(ticket.OwnedBy)` and `Session.Merge(ticket.OwnedBy)` before the SaveOrUpdate(ticket), but the exception is still being thrown. I've also read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862097/nhibernate-dtos-and-nonuniqueobjectexception) about `NonUniqueObjectException`, but calling Session.Lock() didn't work either.

I have two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to bend nHibernate to my will?
2. I may have made an architectural misstep in trying to treat the owners I fetch from AD as the same type as the owners I store in the DB. How can I improve this design so I won't *need* to bend nHibernate to my will?

Comment: How come can you not just do `Ticket.OwnedBy = SecondOwner`, assuming *SecondOwner* is the new owner, and then make a call to **SaveOrUpdate(Ticket)**? Perhaps should you implement an `IInterceptor`?

Comment: Could you show your code wrt how you are replacing the Owner when saving a ticket? Mappings would also help.

Comment: @Will, @James: I updated the post with mappings and the code I use to change the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge works, the most likely issue is you did not call it properly.  Merge will update the existing object with the new object properties but Merge does not attach the new object.  So you have to use the existing one.  If you use the new object after a merge you still get the same error.

The following code should fix the problem:

```
//Merge the new Owner
unitOfWork.Session.Merge(newOwner);

//Get a valid Owner by retrieving from the session
Owner owner = session.Get<Owner>(newOwner.Id);

// Set the ticket to this owner instance instead of the new one
ticket.OwnedBy = owner;

unitOfWork.Session.Update(ticket);
unitOfWork.Commit();
```

The Owner retrieved from the session by Get will have the newOwner properties but also be valid for the session.

Comment: I believe Merge will return a merged object instance so you can do

Owner owner = unitOfWork.Session.Merge(newOwner);

Comment: Good call, saves you the get statement.  You have to cast the object and it should be good to go:                            ticket.OwnedBy = unitOfWork.Session.Merge(newOwner) as Owner

Comment: In my question I said that I tried this and that I was still getting the exception, but after taking a long look at my code I found out that I was also referencing the new, unattached owner from a *completely different* part of my model not mentioned above, and *that* was what was causing the exception. Your answer helped me realize that the problem wasn't where I thought it was, so thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to persist the detached instance of an existing Owner-entity, it should be enough to call merge on the Owner instance without the call to SaveOrUpdate. It will then either insert the entity or update the existing one.

If merge does not work, then something is wrong. Post more code in that case and post your mapping.

BTW: Do you persist the Tickets, too? If so, the mapping seems rather odd. You should have a unique ID on Ticket and Map OwnedBy as a Reference, probably as an inverse mapping with a cascade on it.

Update:
You should map it from both sides. Map the owner-side as a HasMany to Tickets with your Cascade and as Inverse Mapping. Map the Ticket side as Cascade.None() and as a Reference.

```
public TicketMap() {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.OwnedBy)
        .Cascade.None()
        .Not.Nullable();
    /* other properties, etc */
}   

class OwnerMap : ClassMap<Owner> {
public OwnerMap() {
    Id(x => x.Guid)
        .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.Email);
     HasMany<Ticket>(x => x.Tickets).KeyColumn("TicketId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().LazyLoad().Inverse().NotFound.Ignore();
    /* other properties, etc */
}
```

That should work nicely.

Comment: Yes, Ticket is a root domain entity. I don't persist owners directly, only via other domain entities like Ticket. I've also updated the question with mappings and more code.

Comment: Is mapping it from both sides the solution in this case? `Owner` doesn't currently have a `Tickets` collection and my app doesn't have any real need for one. I admit I don't have a very good understanding of NHibernate, but what will this actually do?

Comment: You want a bidirectional mapping. Logically seen, an Owner has many Tickets. Tickets just hold a reference to an owner, but do not posess one.